# How to show more links in custom query_posts and custom loops

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

In This Page http://atthy.com/blog/

I'm using Custom template to show the list of blog posts, Since, I use home.php file to display custom home page. I use `query_posts()` since its a custom template. I created a page in wp admin with the custom `blog Home` template. Everything is fine. But I can't get `read more..` links to work, when using `the_content('read more..')`

When I use `the_content('read more..')` whole post content is displayed without cutting it off after `<!--more-->` and also, read more link is not showing up.

I read through wp codex http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/query_posts and even resetted `global $more` to 0

Here is the page template I'm using. http://pastebin.com/VTvN5dtT

What am I doing wrong?? Please Help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've not tested this myself, but according to http://codex.wordpress.org/Customizing_the_Read_More#How_to_use_Read_More_in_Pages, the

```
global $more;    
$more = 0;
```

needs to be ***inside the loop*** and ***before `the_content('read more..');`***. As such, in your pastebin code, move lines 15-16 to line 30. Like I said, I've not tested this, but give it a whirl and see what happens.

Answer (score 1):

You need to make sure that the statements:

```
global $more;
$more = 0;
```

are placed *after* the call to the_post()